# android, how to show border around a few views inside the constriantLayout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

Using ConstraintLayout to flat the view hierarchy.

In the view there are some views need to show inside a rounded border.

[image]

Did it with a view group as those view's parent container view (here using a nested ConstrainLayout, could be other like RelativeLayout),

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_part_container"
```

But that introduced one more level of the view hierarchy.

Is there a way to group a few views in a visually bordered container but still being only one flat level for all of the views (only one root ContraintLayout)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/a_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="52dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/b_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/b_icon"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/b_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/b_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet " />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/a_avatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/unknown_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_title" />
    <!-- -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a_user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxWidth="220dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/a_user_id_verified"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_title"
        tools:text="ee" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/a_user_id_verified"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/a_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/a_user_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a_user_name"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/phoenix_active_account_tick" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a_user_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/a_user_id_verified"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/a_message_time"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="eee888" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a_message_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a_user_id"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/a_user_id"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a_user_id"
        tools:text="30 Nov 2018" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
        android:textColorLink="@color/red"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a_user_name"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/a_media_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,15:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a_content"
        app:layout_goneMarginBottom="8dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_part_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bk_round_border"
        android:visibility="visible"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/a_reply"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a_media_image"
        app:layout_goneMarginBottom="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a_quoted_user_avatar"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/unknown_avatar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a_user_name_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/a_user_name_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a_user_name_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a_user_name_quoted"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxWidth="220dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="ee 88888888"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/a_quoted_user_avatar"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/a_user_id_verified_quoted"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a_user_id_verified_quoted"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a_user_name_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/a_user_name_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/a_user_id_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a_user_name_quoted"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/phoenix_active_account_tick" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a_user_id_quoted"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="eee88dfdf"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a_user_name_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/a_user_id_verified_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/a_message_time_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a_user_name_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a_message_time_quoted"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            tools:text="30 Nov 2018"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a_user_id_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/a_user_id_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a_user_id_quoted" />

        <!-- -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a_content_quoted"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
            android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
            android:textColorLink="@color/red"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/a_media_image_quoted"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a_user_name_quoted" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a_media_image_quoted"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,15:9"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a_content_quoted"
            app:layout_goneMarginBottom="8dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#20000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a_reply" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try the technique laid out [here](https://constraintlayout.com/cookbook/background.html). There may be another way with the new helpers, but this way should work with all versions of ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @Cheticamp good idea, will try it. Thx!